# how to use a ".class" or ".jar" java file in a c++ file ( without convert )?

Tags: java, c++, jar, .class-file

I want to include and use a ".jar" or some ".class" java files in a ".h" or ".cpp" c++ file .
How can I do this ?
Is there any full helper with example ?

Comment: A Google Search for *Java C++ interop* turns up quite a lot of useful pages.

Comment: Google has many results, for example: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22881/How-to-Call-Java-Functions-from-C-Using-JNI. Stackoverflow requests a basic understanding of the problem at hand with example code of the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You need [JNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface).
Take a look at [this tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22881/How-to-Call-Java-Functions-from-C-Using-JNI).

Also take a look at libraries such as [JunC++](http://www.codemesh.com/products/junction/) and [jace](https://code.google.com/p/jace/) that greatly simplify the work.

Comment: user wants to go the other way around (calling Java from C/C++ not the other way around)

Comment: @rolfl, JNI is a two way street. Read the tutorial and library descriptions.

Comment: K, done. Huh, never used JNI from C. Thanks for the new-to-me info.